# How to manipulate the output of a loop while the script is running

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq $1)
        do
                echo -n '.'
                sleep 1
        done

echo
```

The script prints a dot per second and the number of dots on the screen depending on user's input. What I want to do is that when I press a key (for example, a), the script will run faster like one dot in half a second..so the more I press the same key, the faster it runs.

Comment: So you want to adjust the sleep duration interactively while the script is already running?

Comment: That's correct :D Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable for the duration of the `sleep`:

```
duration=1
# ... inside loop:
                sleep $duration
# ...
```

Then each time a call to `sleep` finishes, have some code to check for new keypresses and alter the value of `$duration` as needed.

On another note, depending on the version of `sleep` you have available, it may not support fractional arguments so you might have to use a separate program like `usleep`.

Comment: One problem is that `sleep` does work with seconds only. So `usleep` would be a better choice since it supports microseconds.

Comment: Ah... my system's `sleep` supports fractional seconds, so it varies. Anyway I'll add that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you help me with the code to check for a keypress?

Comment: @Cailou well that's not what you asked ;-) That would be a matter for a separate question, as I'm not sure of the details offhand but it could be somewhat more complicated.